# React.JS - How to get a onClick to work in a row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple React Component named `Row` which has two other components:

- **`ViewRow`** the actual row that the user can see.
- **`SubRow`**  which is hidden under the `ViewRow`.

What I am trying to accomplish here is add an `onClick` to the `ViewRow` component so that when it is clicked `SubRow` component changes its display from hidden so that the user can see more data on the person.

I have tried a simple button with the same `onClick` and everything works fine; It does a `console.log` of a test string and when used to `setState` it also changes the state successfully. When I try to pass it to the `ViewRow` component it just doesn't do anything, it doesn't even break my code.

**Row Component**

```js
class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: false
    };
    this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
  };

  toggleActive(e) {
    // let currentState = this.state.isActive;
    // this.setState({ isActive: !currentState });
    console.log("button pressed: ")
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/*<button onClick={this.toggleActive.bind(this)}> click </button>*/}

        <ViewRow
          id={this.props.person.id}
          fname={this.props.person["First Name"]}
          lname={this.props.person["Last Name"]}
          birthdate={this.props.person.birthdate}
          email={this.props.person.email}
          gender={this.props.person.gender}
          address={this.props.person.address} 
          onClick={this.toggleActive}
        />

        <SubRow person={this.props.person} />

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

};
```

**ViewRow Component**

```js
class ViewRow extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <tr className="row">
        <ColData className="first" data={this.props.id} />
        <ColData data={this.props.fname} />
        <ColData data={this.props.lname} />
        <ColData data={this.props.birthdate} />
        <ColData data={this.props.email} />
        <ColData data={this.props.gender} />
        <ColData data={this.props.address} />
      </tr>
    );
  }

};
```

**SubRow Component**

```js
class SubRow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr className="hidden">
        <td colSpan="7">
          <div>
            <SubRowContent 
              isActive={this.props.isActive}
              company={this.props.person.company}
              emplid={this.props.person["Employee ID"]}
            />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
};
```

I expect the `onclick` function to change the state so that eventually I can use that to toggle the display for the `SubRow` component.

Comment: pass the active state variable to your `SubRow` component. Use that variable to determine the `hidden` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the state variable to your component so you can display it when you need to

```
class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: false
    };
    this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
  };

  toggleActive(e) {
    // let currentState = this.state.isActive;
    this.setState({ isActive: !currentState });
    console.log("button pressed: ")
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/*<button onClick={this.toggleActive.bind(this)}> click </button>*/}

        <ViewRow
          id={this.props.person.id}
          fname={this.props.person["First Name"]}
          lname={this.props.person["Last Name"]}
          birthdate={this.props.person.birthdate}
          email={this.props.person.email}
          gender={this.props.person.gender}
          address={this.props.person.address} 
          onClick={this.toggleActive}
        />

        <SubRow person={this.props.person} active={this.state.isActive} />

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

};
```

then the subrow can just do this

```
class SubRow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr className={this.props.active ? undefined : "hidden">
        <td colSpan="7">
          <div>
            <SubRowContent 
              isActive={this.props.isActive}
              company={this.props.person.company}
              emplid={this.props.person["Employee ID"]}
            />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
};
```

Feel free to modify as you need to but the gist is there. When you set state to the parent component, pass that flag to the child component that is hidden so you can remove the `hidden` class.